# When a user's content gets flagged, does it leave a trail?

Tags: support, flags

When we flag some content, and the content gets removed, does it leave a trail in the user's history that their content was deleted?

I noticed a lot if noisy comments today while I was looking for questions to answer, so I went through all the newest posts in the tag and flagged noisy comments, including requests to purge all the comments on certain posts.

I couldn't help but notice that a particular user frequently posts a lot of "what have you tried" variants as comments, which got cleaned up after my flagging. These "what have you tried" comments were noisy because other users had already asked OP for clarifications, and this user just adds another "what have you tried" after all the pre-existing comments. On one post, I found up to 28 comments saying the same thing, which is a bit noisy. All my 100 comment flags got exhausted within minutes.

But does this cleanup help? If hundreds of comments of a user require cleanup, does it leave a trail so that moderators can see, if the user is constantly doing this, and maybe some day let them know that they are not being constructive?

I sometimes flag a few answers too, and they get removed. Does that leave a trail? Can moderators see if a lot of posts by a certain user had to be removed?

Comment: Yes it does. And that's what moderators look at when deciding what to do with a problematic user.

Comment: "What have you tried" *variants* aren't necessarily problematic. With those comments, it is entirely the tone that makes them constructive or not constructive. There is no reason to flag constructive comments that ask someone what they've already tried. This is often critical information for composing a good answer.

Comment: A large chunk of my comments are along the lines of "What have you tried?" when randomly scrolling through the main page and looking at the typically hapless questions showing no evidence of what the OP has attempted and thus making the question completely unanswerable. Some of the time the OP even replies and then there's a short conversation in comments before they understand to edit their question but I would certainly say that those comments *are* constructive even if they look chatty after the fact.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Everything always leaves a trail.

For questions and answers, it is extremely easy to notice problematic users because the deleted posts show up in the list when we're viewing that user with the same red background as would be seen for the deleted content. So just browsing through their list of questions, for example, it's hard to miss all that red all over the list.

For comments, though, that does not occur. If we browse through their activity page and sort by comments, the deleted ones don't show up. There is a separate tool in the moderation menu that allows us to view all of their comments, including deleted ones, but unless we noticed a pattern ourselves and explicitly went to look, [we might not notice if a user is having a large number of their comments deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218527/raise-an-automatic-flag-for-many-deleted-comments-from-the-same-user).

Comment: Makes user profiles seem like crime scenes.