# What should be done with users found guilty of plagiarism?

Tags: discussion, moderation, plagiarism

This question is based on a recent case of a user who came to meta and complained about their plagiarized posts being deleted by a moderator, who did not receive any punishment except for losing the reputation points earned by plagiarizing, and was seemingly not even contacted by the moderator. As I couldn't find a guideline or discussion for how plagiarism should be handled by the moderators, I decided to start one myself. Thus:

**How should users found guilty of multiple instances of plagiarism be dealt with? Is it enough to simply delete the plagiarized posts?**

Note that I'm talking about copypasting entire Stack Overflow posts (or Wikipedia articles, etc.) verbatim without attribution. Less serious instances (e.g. including a few bits of documentation in a larger answer, but failing to quote them properly) are not in the scope of this post.

Comment: I'm obviously not privy to the specifics of this case, but it wasn't uncommon for users to either ignore a mod message or feign ignorance when confronted with plagiarism or vote fraud. It's possible that they were contacted by a moderator privately.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I suspected that might have been a possibility, that's why I said "_seemingly_ not contacted". I've never received a mod message and thus I don't know how easily missable it is - is it just a normal inbox message as for an answer or comment?

Comment: Yes, it just shows up as an inbox message. It can be easy to overlook if it's just a warning.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: I can't not imagine you saying that first part with a completely disheartened look on your face.

Comment: @BilltheLizard ah, that might be the issue - IMO a mod warning should be similar in impact as the suspension banner; not just a small red `[1]` in the top bar. Or would that interfere with other ways in which warnings are currently used by mods?

Comment: @BoltClock No, I trust you guys. You can handle it. I don't need to see the specific details. I can let go, really I can!

Comment: "Off with their heads!" (*Queen of Hearts*, in *Alice in wonderlands*, by Lewis Carroll)

Comment: Put them in the [iron maiden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_maiden)

Answer (score 122):

As a moderator, I take accusations of plagiarism seriously. Plagiarism is a personal pet peeve of mine, largely because I come from an academic background and almost had my career ruined by someone who attempted to take credit for my work.

That said, here is how I handle people accused of plagiarism. First, I verify the claims. You'd be surprised at the number of people who accuse others of plagiarism just because they both arrived at the same snippet of code independently (or they just want to destroy their competition). I need to see clear indication that something was copied from something else, usually involving copied wording.

Once I've established that a post was copied from somewhere else without proper attribution (and no, just tacking a link on the end of an entirely copied answer is not proper attribution), I leave a comment to that effect and delete the post. This isn't so much to bring this to the attention of the poster, but to act as a reference for when people question why something was deleted. I don't edit the post to provide proper attribution, except in rare cases, because I consider that burden to be on the poster if they want their content to be restored.

Next, I will examine if this is a pattern of behavior for this person. Is this the only post they've plagiarized? If it is, and they haven't done this before, I tend to move on and work on other things.

If they have plagiarized more than one post, we have a standard moderator message of warning about this. That message is then sent to the user, which clearly states that plagiarism is unacceptable here and that all content must be properly attributed to the source (with guidelines on how to do so).

We do not suspend at this point, because it has been our experience that many users from certain areas of the world do not realize that what they are doing is wrong. Therefore, we try to educate these users before taking more serious action. In the vast majority of cases, that's all that is needed to get them on the right track.

However, certain people still keep doing this despite warnings. It is at that point that we impose more serious penalties. Suspension of an account comes with the next incident of plagiarism, and we can even delete accounts if it is clear that they will never contribute anything original.

If there is a combination of plagiarism with voting fraud, we've been known to skip warnings and go straight to account suspension or deletion. Ultimately, each case is a judgment call by the moderator involved, but that's how I handle accusations of plagiarism.

Comment: Mine is pretty close to that too.  The only 'difference' (if you can even call it that) is that I pay close attention to intent and effect of the plagiarism. That weighs more heavily on my decisions than most other considerations.

Comment: I heavily disagree with not suspending the users. Some users might come from more casual forums or image boards and might not realize that certain lingo and insults are not acceptable on SO - I would still want them suspended. There were also long term high profile suspensions for users being "rude" (or IMO simply not sugarcoating feedback or putting up with too much crap). How is this different?

Comment: @l4mpi [A Theory of Moderation](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) spells out how we should adjudicate these issues: *"The ideal moderator does as little as possible. But those little actions may be powerful and highly concentrated. Judiciously limiting your use of moderator powers to selectively prune and guide the community -- now that's the true art of moderation."*

Comment: @l4mpi - Our goal is not to apply punishment, it is to prevent problematic behavior. If I can do that by simply warning someone, which we have seen to be the case for many first-time plagiarists, then there is no need for the suspension. Suspending someone can often lead to a significant amount of anger, which makes it much less likely they'll reform their behavior and increases the odds of someone becoming a much worse problem. If we can avoid that in most cases, great.

Comment: @BradLarson If I had a nickel for every time I saw a mod message response that was negative, we could power Stack Exchange just through their anger.

Comment: As far as the "high profile" suspensions, you'll find in many cases that [we gave them a number of warnings in an attempt to change their behavior](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281561/is-there-anything-appropriate-community-members-can-do-to-lift-another-users-pe/281579#281579), only to have them continue or get worse. The first warnings almost always came without suspensions. We give people many opportunities to behave well here, but if they show no signs of doing so we may ask them to leave.

Comment: @BradLarson well, not suspending those users also leads to a significant amount of anger, just in other people. Do you value me and potentially others being angry as less important than plagiarists being angry?

Comment: I think that's why these things are usually kept between the plagiarists and the moderators.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thing is, they're usually never _just_ between plagiarists and mods. I myself have reported quite a few cases of plagiarism, on 5 or 6 different users this year already. I think one of the accounts was nuked and two or three others were short-term suspended, not sure about the rest. But I do regularily check the result of my flags, and would thus be able to see if a user was suspended or not even if they don't come to meta and cry about it.

Comment: @l4mpi: it is our job to handle and reform misbehaving users. If avoiding angering them needlessly helps us in doing that job, we avoid needlessly angering them. Are you saying that angering you in that process will mean we'll have more work in the future?

Comment: @MartijnPieters of course. If the result of me flagging something, be it plagiarism or anything else, is discouraging me from doing so, I will reconsider if it's worth my time (or how much of my time it's worth). Just as my frustration with the way SE is handling the content quality debate led to me stop to searching for questions to answer, I might stop flagging things, which is basically all I do on SO nowadays except for closevoting.

Comment: @l4mpi: I'd have hoped you flag to help protect the integrity of our content and model. If all you are flagging for is the satisfaction of seeing someone being punished, you might be flagging for the wrong reasons. Please trust that we handle these cases to minimise repeat behaviour.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I _am_ flagging and closevoting to attempt to keep SO as high-quality as possible. I'm just not at all convinced that a soft stance on things like plagiarism or post quality is helpful - it certainly doesn't seem to be the case with low quality questions.

Comment: Brad, would enjoy seeing a couple examples in your answer of "bad copied text" (plagiarized text without attribution) and "ok copied text" (text copied from elsewhere with an appropriate attribution)? (Obviously for brevity you could keep the examples to a sentence or so).

Comment: @remus - Bad (deleted): http://stackoverflow.com/a/31452590/19679 , OK (after I edited it): http://stackoverflow.com/a/28579827/19679 . Proper attribution begins with a link to the original content, should indicate the author of that, and all copied text must be placed within blockquotes to indicate authorship.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker And who can say you don't already...

Comment: This reminds me of this case of plagiarism I stumbled upon today: Suneel Gupta copied all content, ***except the author information***, to *[Implementing a Basic Hello World WCF Service](http://mycodelogic.blogspot.dk/2011/07/implementing-basic-hello-world-wcf.html)*. The original article is *[Implementing a Basic Hello World WCF Service](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mikeliu88/implementing-a-basic-hello-world-wcf-service/)* by [Mike Liu](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/authors/mikeliu88/mike-liu.aspx).

Comment: @PeterMortensen: alas, I think that's outside SO moderators' reach.

Comment: It is nice you realise that not every part of the world aware that plagiarism is wrong and unethical. Some people think that it is just a "bad manner" not giving credit to original author.

Comment: @tia: Some people don't even think *that* - they don't even have a concept of ownership or intellectual property.

Comment: @PeterMortensen. You can report that at http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177/147191. Yes, the SCRAPERS stuff is mainly about people doing this in bulk, but individual acts do still count.

Comment: Another good reason to apply gradually increased moderation is no one is perfect, and moderators do make mistakes. It is very frustrating to be a part of a community with heavy handed moderators, because when they make mistakes, those mistakes involve severe outcomes that are difficult to get reversed. If you make a mistake with a rock, usually someone is a little bruised, but if you make a mistake with a nuclear missile, that is a bit more damaging.

Answer (score 18):

We handle every case on a case-by-case basis. The actions we take depend on the *specific* circumstances surrounding the alleged infraction.

I know you want a one-size-fits-all. There isn't one.  If there were, you wouldn't need moderators, you could simply create a feature request for an algorithm and have it police plagiarism.

If that's what your question is asking for, perhaps you're better suited [asking for a feature request to implement said algorithm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171876/automate-on-site-plagiarism-detection)?

The reason we don't have one is that we already take a variety of actions depending on *the specific set of circumstances surrounding the alleged infractions*, and each instance is different.

The reason we don't broadcast punishments among the roof tops is that [that's not the kind of community we want](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/618324806937657344).

Comment: You missed a golden opportunity to steal that tweet and present it as your own.

Comment: @BoltClock I see what you did there. It actually took me a few minutes, but I got it.

Comment: I don't want a one-size-fits-all solution, I just think there should be clear, community-agreed guidelines for how plagiarists should be handled. I for one can't think of too many specific circumstances for cases where it's crystal clear that the content is plagiarized. We should be able to break this down to a few base cases, right?

Comment: @l4mpi I allude to it in my comment on Brad Larson's answer. The intent and the *effect* (emphasis added) of the plagiarism counts towards how we adjudicate it.

Comment: It's hard to get two people to agree on anything all the time so a standardized approach to this problem IMO is too much to ask. You're right, a case by case basis is what's needed, you also need to be aware that sometimes (rarely) short sections may match somewhere else on the web either by two people arriving at the same conclusion independently or quoting from memory and not being aware of where the user has read it before.

Answer (score -11):

My proposed way of handling those cases:

First of all, **deletion of the plagiarized posts is *never* enough** - a user should at least be warned by a mod.

If it's only a single plagiarized post and there are no other significant issues with the user (such as having a history of bad behaviour), the post should be deleted and the user should receive a warning.

If multiple posts were plagiarized, they should be deleted and **the user should be suspended** for a while. The duration of the suspension should roughly scale with the amount of plagiarized posts.

In severe cases, e.g. if the majority of a users posts are found to be the result of plagiarism, the user could even be deleted outright (as long as that doesn't cause more work for the mods than cleaning up the posts and long-term suspending the user).

---

One argument that often comes up in discussions about plagiarism is that "some cultures don't have a concept of plagiarism" and "the users didn't know what they were doing was bad". While I'm not capable of verifying that claim (and doubt that it is true for *professional and enthusiast* programmers who should all have heard of source code licenses etc regardless of their origin), I would answer that *it is not a reason not to take action against a user*. A short suspension should serve as an educational measure, as long as the user is given adequate resources to understand the reasons for it.

Comment: You know, you could just decide to trust the elected moderators, and their combined decades of experience with dealing with fraud.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's not an issue of trust, more of consistency and community consensus. I think it should be clearly defined how such cases should be handled; and right now it's apparently not. As described in the question, it's not a hypothetical question either, I'm asking because of a concrete situation that happened just an hour ago. I had a discussion with George Stocker on his answer to the question I mention as for why a plagiarizing user would not be suspended, but he said it would be "inappropriate" to discuss, which I disagree with - at least for the general case.

Comment: Yes, I know about the discussion, which is *why* I commented the way I did.

Comment: @MartijnPieters if you know about the discussion and thus the related question, what do you think went wrong if the plagiarising user was apparently not even informed why their questions were deleted? Or don't you think that's an issue?

Comment: Except the plagiarist *was* informed, which they flat-out denied. IIRC moderator comments on deleted posts should remain in a user's inbox long after the posts have remained deleted, since we can comment on deleted posts to start with.

Comment: @BoltClock ok, let's assume they were informed - I was under the impression that a moderator warning is _not_ easy to miss, which doesn't seem to be the case. Still, why was a user with multiple plagiarized posts not suspended? I'd assume that would be a serious offense. But anyways, this is less about the specific case and more about what should be done in the general case - should users with multiple plagiarized posts be suspended or not? I'd say yes, absolutely.

Comment: @l4mpi, but was it a repeated offense? If it wasn't, well... everyone deserves a second chance, so to speak.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi in the specific case which caused the question, it was at least three posts (and the user only has 4 visible questions atm, so it was a relatively huge amount of their contributions). IMO that counts as a "repeat offense". And of course people can get a second chance, that's why they should be suspended and not deleted instantly. A few days away from SO seems like the perfect opportunity to reflect on their actions.

Comment: @l4mpi, to me *repeated offense* would mean the user plagiarized three posts, was warned by the moderation team, and *then* persisted in their behavior. I'm not sure it's the case here.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi that was not the case AFAIK, but why would you not suspend someone for, say, three days in such a case? They still get a second chance, _in three days_. Your position assumes that the user doesn't know that anything is wrong with just copypasting stuff _and that we should tolerate that_ by not punishing them as hard - I fail to see why.

Comment: FWIW I'd much rather be impartial myself and make a decision based solely on the scale of plagiarism regardless of whether the user was ignorant. But, seeing the rate at which this has been happening over the years, I hate to admit it but I think we're going to have to start spelling out certain things that are in fact common sense in most of the developed world in order for that to work.

Comment: @l4mpi, plagiarism should not be tolerated, I agree, but harshness in punishment is not a simple problem. We actually have the exact same problem with our respective penal systems, with some people thinking prison times are too hard and others thinking they're too light. That's why delegating the decision to an elected body (the moderation team in our case) is not such a bad idea.

Comment: "some cultures don't have a concept of plagiarism" true, but closed-source software and open-source software cultures both frown upon it; they've got different views on *copying*, but neither works well if unacknowledged copying happens.

Comment: @Jon Hanna: That argument isn't about software cultures though...

Comment: @BoltClock and that's why that argument is irrelevant on SO.