# copy/pasting an answer from a different website with citing

Tags: discussion

I was hoping we could clarify some policy pertaining to finding an answer on another website. I was somewhat recently downvoted for copy/pasting an answer for someone with including a citation for the website I found it on. Is this because the answer/example I posted was easy to find via a quick google search and might promote lazy posters? Shouldn't the rule be the same whether it appears on page 1 or page 101 of the search? Any clarification here would be appreciated. Thanks!

post I made reference to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31485254/what-language-framework-should-i-use-to-create-a-drag-and-drop-enabled-gui/31485485#31485485

Comment: Could you disclose the answer by linking please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31485254/what-language-framework-should-i-use-to-create-a-drag-and-drop-enabled-gui/31485485#31485485

Comment: Did the person who down voted actually say that's why they did it? I don't see a comment explanation on the question I'm pretty sure you're talking about.

Comment: comment has since been deleted, however I am still curious about whether this is acceptable or not

Comment: @peggy, answering recommendation questions like that one is dubious in the first place. With an example copy-pasted from the web, doubly so (even attributed).

Comment: with him not posting any code, what else makes sense to do beside giving him a simple easy to understand example? So it's better to not answer him at all and not help someone when I'm able to?

Comment: According to [this answer by a mod](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299784/4076315), just putting a link to the URL at the end is not sufficient attribution. Currently searching for guidance on how to correctly attribute answers on SO for off site resources. (Mostly finding questions on how to attribute SO itself properly.)

Comment: _So it's better to not answer him at all_ @peggy - If you want to help an Asker who's question is off topic, you can help them make it on topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the question itself was closed as being off-topic because asking for 3rd party resources.

You should bear in mind, that answering such questions, might give future researchers the impression it's legit, and they will receive an answer with such questions.

Though there's nothing else fundamentally wrong with your answer. What you propose is well suited for what the OP's looking for.

Comment: so for example, let's say he knew he wanted to make a drag-n-drop app with swing and posted a couple of lines of code he barely got started with. This way the post would be in the guidelines of SO. Is it then acceptable to give such an answer?

Comment: @peggy if it were an on topic question, your answer would be ok just by adding attribution to the original author (Jan Bodnar).