# Copy paste from a msdn Blog

Tags: discussion, answers

Reading an old question, I found an answer that has 2.5% difference with a 4000char msdn post. 
But with a reference at the end of the copy past( the 2.5% is the link ).

I have try to find the licencing of msdn post like this one : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/12/14/use-the-right-tool-for-the-job/

Is it ok to copy past a full blog Msdn Blog post and add a reference?

---

Timeline:

2009, Mr lippert make a blog post.
2010, Robert ask about a the same topic on So.
2010, Janes link to the Lippert post in comment.
Till 2015 comment were upvoted 10 times.
2015, Joe copy pasta 100% of Lippert post, add reference.

Comment: Do I have to disclose the post i am talking about?

Comment: Did Eric Lippert write the answer by any chance?

Comment: What's the date of answer here? If it came before the blog post...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, add a revelant timeline

Comment: @BilltheLizard, Do you have Mr. Lippert number? I will be asking him directly!

Comment: According to this [moderator answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299784/6560478) it's not ok. Tooke me a long time to find this.

Comment: First: stuff on my MSDN blog was written by me while on the clock at Microsoft, and the copyright is held by Microsoft. Questions about republishing MSDN blog content should go to Microsoft's lawyers, not to me. Second, my *personal* opinion is that republishing stuff I wrote is silly; just link to it.

Comment: If someone is going to republish regardless of what I or MSFT's lawyers think then my requests are that the republisher (1) link back to the original, (2) acknowledge my authorship, (3) not quote out of context to create a misleading impression, (4) not modify beyond formatting, and (5) not expect me to make corrections or respond to comments on a platform I have no control over.