# I've been (falsely, in my opinion) accused of plagiarism. Some guidelines

Tags: discussion, moderation, plagiarism

I commented on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47762031/start-process-a-file-without-extension-in-vb-net/47763682?noredirect=1#comment82490431_47763682), and, since the OP asked me, I gave him an answer.

The code I used comes from a library I made, years ago. I translated it to VB.NET (from C#), prepared, and posted it. All in, say, 10 minutes.

Then, out of the blue, some guy accused me of "stealing" someone else's work, because the names of the flags and enumerator list I posted were *identical* to those he found in [PInvoke](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shlwapi/AssocQueryString.html) and in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162331/finding-the-default-application-for-opening-a-particular-file-type-on-windows) here.

I tried to explain that those are not just names, but **the** names, those you can find in `Shlwapi.h` and of course in MSDN. That's why everyone is using them.

That's the standard naming convention for those values (and not only those) when used in C# or VB.NET.

He also mentioned that the name of a function was identical. `AssocQueryString`? That's the name in Shlwapi.dll library. He clearly didn't know much about it, said something else, downvoted both question and answer and disappeared.

However, this event, per se, is not really important. (Even though I'd like to know your opinion on this.)

I wrote here because this made me think. I know the abstract of "what should be considered plagiarism", so I'm more interested in what is considered or perceived as such *here*.

Given that I've been writing here for more or less a month, I don't have a good grasp of the community culture and *mood* yet.

So I took my tour. I read [the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) on this. Well, those are the standard, basic rules you can find anywhere else (*yes, right*...).
I found some (apparently plagiarized) [cats explaining the accepted behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83955/plagiarism-should-be-addressed-specifically-in-the-faq/134715#134715).

Other posts are more related to *[What should be done with users found guilty of plagiarism?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299777/what-should-be-done-with-users-found-guilty-of-plagiarism)*. The opinions on the matter, well, they show controversial *feelings* (and when they don't).

I wrote "Guidelines", but in truth what I care about is some experienced advice.

Also, in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/users-are-calling-me-a-plagiarist-what-do-i-do) I found a reference to the moderators:

> ...moderators are entrusted to reach a decision that benefits the
>   site...

In a case like this, what is the preferred behavior and/or outcome?

- Moderators take care of this, there's nothing else to be done.
- Address/Ask a moderator (how?) (to what end?).
- It's a personal matter. Deal with it in chat or suck it up.
- That is one post, among millions, nobody cares.
- (...)

I'm asking this out of respect for what people do here, some on a daily basis.

Also, having the suspect of being seen as some sort of pariah for reasons I may not understand, is unpleasant. If my question is so "green" that I deserve a kick in the teeth, that's fine, I can take it.

Comment: Meh, it's one person who unreasonably (I assume) accused you of plagiarism and is unwilling to listen. It doesn't feel nice but it happens, shouldn't be too often though. You present a good case fighting back in the comments for any future viewers who may care. I'd leave it at that and move on. As to "what is plagiarism"... I guess ultimately it's a "I know it when I see it" kind of thing. As far as I can judge your case, not speaking the language, it is definitely not plagiarism and definitely not worthy of a downvote.

Comment: The guy is ignorant, no need to pay attention to his comments.  We try to fix ignorance here but if they don't want to listen then there is little you can do.  Easy to fix the downvote, done.

Comment: @Pekka 웃 Thank you for answering. I saw your nick in many posts on this subject. I'm not that much interested in winning a fight, it's more the idea that I'm "missing something" that I don't like.

Comment: @Hans Passant  Allright, got it. I really appreciate an answer from you. You didn't need to upvote, I didn't come to SO for the "badges". Thank you anyway.

Comment: The meta effect is going to kick in on your answer, whether you like it or not (trust me, you're probably going to like it).

Comment: @HansPassant We try to fix ignorance, [but some people just will never accept the help.](http://dilbert.com/strip/2011-10-14)

Comment: Stay away from the badges, that's how they get you hooked >.<

Comment: @Peter Cordes  Yep, that's how _they_ do it... I don't want badges. I think I want a cap, though... Ah, bummer, I think They got me! The deceivers! Mhmm... I think I need a cap. Oh, come on, I'm better than that! ...and I have 3! Can I sell those I don't use? Nah, you never ever run out of caps! I think I'll keep'em. My precious...

Comment: @Jimi: Yes, Stack Overflow has been very successful at getting me to... write a lot of good stuff which many people have found useful and interesting?  So evil? wait, no, what?

Comment: So, this was your first post on meta? Yeah, you will do just fine here. Don't worry about negative comments on your answers, that is kind of normal from time to time (unfortunately). Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Moderators take plagiarism accusations seriously. That doesn't mean we believe any accusation of plagiarism and delete the offending post right away. It means we evaluate the accusation and determine

- if the author is indeed trying to pass other people's work off as their own,
- if they aren't, but the code comes from a well-known source such as a standard library or some other well-documented "omnipresent" source, or
- if the work is in fact their own.

Given that `AssocQueryString()` is a method name from a built-in library that's documented on MSDN, I don't think there's much else to say about it (other than, what, it was written by Microsoft?). I mean, your declaration literally contains the name of said library. I don't see what's there to dispute about it, or how you've "plagiarized" it in any way. In fact, the comments from that user come across as if they don't know how P/Invokes work at all. It might be worth educating them politely in the comments about them. (To be fair, I can only say this because I know a [thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493149/how-do-i-make-a-wpf-window-movable-by-dragging-the-extended-window-frame/5494769#5494769) or [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660976/get-the-active-color-of-windows-8-automatic-color-theme/13670173#13670173) about them — not all moderators may possess the domain knowledge required to evaluate a plagiarism accusation, and that's why we have a whole team of them across a variety of tags.)

I don't think you need to be much more explicit about the fact that the implementation of the declaration is your own. When you post an answer, you implicitly call your own anything that you haven't otherwise stated isn't yours. Then again, that's not what that user was taking issue with.

Fortunately for you, the user who accused you didn't raise a flag on your post. It probably means they weren't sure enough to start alerting us about it. But even if they did flag your post, rest assured if you did nothing wrong we'll do our best to clear your name.

Comment: ♦  The point of view of a moderator is probably the answer I was looking for. When you say _When you post an answer, you implicitly call your own anything that you haven't otherwise stated isn't yours_ you mean that I take responsability of what I'm saying?

Comment: @Jimi: Yes, pretty much. After all, your answers are contributed under your own name.

Comment: ♦  Perfect. I think I have what I needed. Thank you for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 13):

When it comes to code, plagiarism is when you copy/paste a whole code from elsewhere and post it with no attribution given. (Possibly only changing the names of identifiers.)

Using definitions, enums, constants etc as required by a certain API is *not* plagiarism. Of course it doesn't hurt to link the API documentation as source, but this isn't really necessary.

When it comes to documentation and text, it should be placed in quote formatting and the source should be mentioned.

As for quoting other SO posts, it is often not a good idea, since that usually means that you are dealing with a duplicate question that should be closed.

---

> In a case like this, what is the preferred behavior and/or outcome?

In case the poster simply forgot to state the source, this could be fixed by asking for clarification or by editing the answer and including a reference to the original source.

If one user suspects that another user is deliberately plagiarizing, then the preferred action is to flag the post for diamond moderator attention. Include a link to the original source and let the moderators deal with it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Good advices here, too. I did link the official documentation a couple of times, but as a plus. I didn't think to do it regularly. I'm going to change this.